# Docker error C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Tags: bash, git, docker

After the cloning of wappalyzer repository in git bash and running the command 
`$ git clone https://github.com/<your_github_username>/Wappalyzer.git
$ cd Wappalyzer
$ ./run links`

After the command `./run links` the error is
`vipul rao@Rao MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/wappalyzer
$ ./run links
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/master/run`](https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/master/run) script is supposed to run in a linux session, not a Windows mingw Git bash.

See [this issue](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/OpenDroneMap/issues/591#issuecomment-343745792) as a similar example:

> It should work after changing path to lowercase

```
docker run -it -v "C:/Users/rburton/code/Docker/R:/home/docker".ToLower() -w /home/docker -u docker --rm /usr/bin/bash
```

In your case, change in the run script the docker command in order to hard-code (for testing) your local volume path in lowercase, using the `/c/my/path/in/lowercase` syntax.

In this instance, modify the [run script](https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/master/run) to echo the docker command

```
cmd="docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/opt/wappalyzer" -it wappalyzer/dev"
echo "${cmd}"
```

Then, when you see the string displayed with an actual path in it:

```
docker run --rm -v "/C/Users...:/opt/wapppalyzer" -it wappalyzer/dev"
```

Add in the script, for testing, the same path in lowercase:

```
cmd="docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/opt/wappalyzer" -it wappalyzer/dev"
cmd="docker run --rm -v "/c/users/...:/opt/wappalyzer" -it wappalyzer/dev"
# that second cld= will override the first
# use the path displayed by the echo, but in lowercase: /c/users/..., not /C/Users/...
echo "${cmd}"
```

Comment: I have downloaded from "https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer" how to run this on windows/is it possible to run this on windows and how to use this git repo i have no idea where exactly to save this and run this.can you please help

Comment: You are running it. Modify the script to echo the run command, then modify it again to this time run the docker command in lowercase

Comment: can you be specific to where and what to modify

Comment: @VipulRao I have edited the answer to be more specific

Comment: After following the steps you mentioned i still have the same error           `$ docker run --rm -v /c/users/vipul rao/documents/github/wappalyzer:/opt/wappalyzer -it wappalyzer/dev
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.`

Comment: @VipulRao I see a space: make sure your command use quotes around the local volume mounted path: `docker run --rm -v "/c/users/vipul rao/documents/github/wappalyzer:/opt/wappalyzer" -it wappalyzer/dev`

Comment: if you have multiple lines of command better to take them all into one line. https://lingojam.com/TexttoOneLine can be used for it.